# JavaScript: Repeated String single test failure

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve the [HackerRank's Repeated String Challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string).
The description of the challenge is below:

> There is a string, *s*, of lowercase English letters that is repeated infinitely many times. Given an integer,*n*, find and print the number of letter a's in the first letters of the infinite string.

My solution passes all the 20 test cases except 1 test case (Test case no. 7).

Test Case no. 7:

```
Input: 
kmretasscityylpdhuwjirnqimlkcgxubxmsxpypgzxtenweirknjtasxtvxemtwxuarabssvqdnktqadhyktagjxoanknhgilnm
736778906400

Expected Output: 51574523448
Actual Output:   5157452344800
```

My Solution:

```
function repeatedString(s, n) {
    
    if (s.length === 0) return; 
    let count = 0;
    if (n < s.length) {
        for (let i=0; i<n; i++){
            s.charAt(i) === 'a' ? count++ : null;
        }
        return count;
    }
    for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++){
        s.charAt(i) === 'a' ? count++ : null;
    }
    if (n % s.length === 0){
        return count * n;
    } else if (n % s.length !== 0){
        let extra = n % s.length;
        let extraCount = 0;
        for (let i=0; i<extra; i++){
            s.charAt(i) === 'a' ? extraCount++ : null;
        }
        return count * (Math.trunc(n/s.length)) + extraCount;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I am unable to understand the issue. What I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if (n % s.length === 0){
  return count * n;
}
```

In the above block of code, you're multiplying the number of occurrences of `'a'` (`count`) with `n` but you should be multiplying it with the number of times the string is repeated (i.e. `n / s.length`).

e.g.

`s` = `'ab'`, `n` = `10`

`count` = `1` (`'a'` appears once)

Since `n % s.length === 0`, your code returns `count * n` => 10 but the string `'ab'` is only repeated 5 (`n / s.length`) times - `'ababababab'`. So, it should return `count * (n / s.length)` => 5.

```js
if (n % s.length === 0) {
  return count * (n / s.length)
}
```

The whole code:

```js
const repeatedString = (s, n) => {
  if (s.length === 0) {
    return
  }
  let count = 0
  if (n < s.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      s.charAt(i) === 'a' ? count++ : null
    }
    return count
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    s.charAt(i) === 'a' ? count++ : null
  }
  if (n % s.length === 0) {
    return count * (n / s.length)
  }
  const extra = n % s.length
  let extraCount = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < extra; i++) {
    s.charAt(i) === 'a' ? extraCount++ : null
  }
  return count * Math.trunc(n / s.length) + extraCount

  return count
}

console.log(
  repeatedString(
    'kmretasscityylpdhuwjirnqimlkcgxubxmsxpypgzxtenweirknjtasxtvxemtwxuarabssvqdnktqadhyktagjxoanknhgilnm',
    736778906400
  )
)
```

---

This is unrelated to the question but you don't need to use `else if`.

```js
if (n % s.length === 0) {
  return count * (n / s.length)
}

const extra = n % s.length
//....
// return ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way to approach this would be to

- make a function that counts up the number of matching characters in a string
- identify how many times the input string fits into the span being searched *whole*, and identify how many characters are in the remainder. For example, if you're searching the first 23 characters, and the string is 10 characters long, you have 2 * 20 with 3 trailing characters.
- count up the number of occurrences in the single whole string, multiply by the number of times the whole string fits into the span being searched
- add the above by the number of occurrences in the sliced trailing characters

```js
const repeatedString = (s, n) => {
  const strLen = s.length;
  const fullStringRepetitions = Math.floor(n / strLen);
  const trailingCharacterCount = n - (strLen * fullStringRepetitions);
  const trailingCharacters = s.slice(0, trailingCharacterCount);

  const getCharCount = str => [...str].reduce((a, b) => a + (b === 'a'), 0);
  return (
    fullStringRepetitions * getCharCount(s) +
    getCharCount(trailingCharacters)
  );
};
console.log(repeatedString('kmretasscityylpdhuwjirnqimlkcgxubxmsxpypgzxtenweirknjtasxtvxemtwxuarabssvqdnktqadhyktagjxoanknhgilnm', 736778906400));
```

Comment: I did not ask for a better approach. I am asking to find the issue with my approach.